# Selenium-How to find the exact text using selenium-eclipse-mozilla

Tags: java, selenium, automation

Am new to Selenium RC and currently am using Java to run the scripts.Below is the scenario

## Scenario

I am trying to login to my appliation, once i login have to find the login/user name. Once i find the login/username i will perfom/click on different link else logout.After loging in am not able to verify the text i really want to.

Pls find the code below.

Thanks in advance.

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;

public class TestRun {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Selenium selenium=new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444 , "*firefox","myurl");
        selenium.start();
        selenium.open("myurl");
        System.out.println("Open browser "+selenium);
        selenium.windowMaximize();
        selenium.type("id=j_username","Lal");
        selenium.type("name=j_password","lal");
        System.out.println(selenium.isElementPresent("id=j_username"));
        selenium.click("name=submit");
                    if(selenium.isTextPresent("Lal"))
        {
            selenium.click("id=common_header_logout");
        }
                    else
        {
            System.out.println("User not found");
        }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have need to wait for some time before using "isElementPresent" if previous command is click.

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Selenium selenium=new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444 , "*firefox","myurl");
    selenium.start();
    selenium.open("myurl");
    System.out.println("Open browser "+selenium);
    selenium.windowMaximize();
    selenium.type("id=j_username","Lal");
    selenium.type("name=j_password","lal");
    selenium.click("name=submit");
    **selenium.waitForPageToLoad("60000");**
    if(selenium.isTextPresent("Lal"))
    {
        selenium.click("id=common_header_logout");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("User not found");
    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks a lot Hemant. It worked grt. Would like to calrify few things.

Comment: Thanks a lot Hemant. It worked grt. Would like to calrify few things as am starting my selenium server , each time i run my prg i get untrusted connection is firefox. So in order to run the application i have to add exception and confirm the security exception which is a painful task. Is there a way to come out of it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have need to create a firefox profile to handle security certificate issues and other things.

Answer (score 0):

===============================================================

## Firefox profile for handling SSL certificate exceptions in Selenium Automation

1. Make sure all your firefox instance are closed
2. Click Start>Run
3. Type "firefox.exe -ProfileManager -no-remote"
4. Select "Create Profile"
5. Click Next button.
6. Enter new profile name (i.e. SeleniumProfile)
7. Select a directory folder to store your new profile.
8. Finish
9. Click on "Start Firefox" and configure settings .
10. From "View\Toolbars" tab, uncheck "Bookmarks Toolbar"
11. Right click from toolbar and click "Customize".
12. Remove "Google search" by dragging it to the "Customize Toolbar" window
13. From the "Customize Toolbar" window, click "Use Small Icons" check box then hit "Done"
14. Click "Tools\Options" then set the following:
    a). "Main" tab

    - set Home Page to "about:blank"
    - uncheck "Show the Downloads.." option

    b). "Tabs" tab

    - Select 'a new window" for new pages
    - Uncheck all warning options

    c). "Content" tab

    - uncheck "Block pop-up" windows option

    d). "Privacy" tab

    - uncheck all "History" options

    e). "Security" tab

    - uncheck all "Security" options
    - click "Settings" and uncheck all warning options

    f). "Advanced" tab

    - Uncheck "autoscrolling" option from "General" tab
    - uncheck "warn me …" and "Ssearch Engines" option from "Update" tab
15. Open site which is have certificate error. When get error follwing steps takes place

    - Add Exception: Select Encryption, Click on ViewCertificate and click on AddException
      type "https://cretificateurl.com" in location and get certificate and then click on
      "Confirm Security Exception" and press OK.
16. In address bar type "about:config" and add the following by right-click anywhere
    on the page and selecting "new"

    - extensions.update.notifyUser (type=boolean; value=false)
    - extensions.newAddons (type=boolean; value=false)
17. Run selenium server using 
    java -jar selenium-server.jar -firefoxProfileTemplate ""

Comment: Tried the above steps, but @ step 15 i did not get any AddException type. I just confirmed security exception and moved on to the next steps. But now if i run my script tru eclipse after restarting the server i still get this untrusted site every time.

Comment: Rajeev for adding exception in step 15, you can go with following steps:                                                                  paste security certificate url on following path:

Mozila-> options-> advance-> view Certificate-> Server->add exception

Comment: Hemant- Tried adding it at 15th step, but am facing the same prb.